# two pages aside with headers and footers

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to make a document that looks like this:[image]

as you can see it's like having 2 A5 sheets side by side. Yes, I can do it, but the problem is how to do separate headers and footers. When I set up a header or a footer it places like this:[image]

How to create separate headers and footers?

Comment: Why not just setup a document in A5 format? Once it's done, you'll simply print it on A4 paper. Am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: the document will be distributed online, so printing is not an option :(

Comment: I'd still work with A5, as far as the initial LaTeX is concerned, and then use a script  to rearrange the individual pages as a printable booklet for distribution. In fact I have done just that that on multiple occasions with some success.

Comment: You should show your code. Currently it is unknown how to know that the footer goes over two pages. E.g. do you draw lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution to my problem. Using the method from https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfmorepages/pgfmorepages.pdf it is possible to set the layout of pages using `pgfpages` with just one line of code!
`\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper, landscape]`